# AP does not have assigned IP address by DHCP

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, dhcp, ip-address

I have aironet-1242 and air-cap2600i AP's, infact I'm trying to upload image on to my PC through TFTP, as I assign static IP address to fastethernet or BVI interfaces and start uploading, AP connectivity gets drop and AP reverted back to DHCP, find this message "Could not discover WLC using static IP. Forcing AP to use DHCP" now issue is when I do "show ip int brief fa0/BVI1 " I get this 
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Prot                                                                                        ocol
FastEthernet0              unassigned      YES DHCP   up                    up

Please give me the solution, how can i get DHCP assigned address, I will be very thankful.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your access point are the controller based version, I.E. lightweight, that means they are supposed to connect to a Wireless Lan Controller ("WLC")

At startup the access points get an IP from DHCP then try (by several methods) to join a WLC. When they fell to do so, they reset their network interface and try again until they succeed.

You cannot use such AP (with this software) without a WLC.

They can be converted to autonomous (standalone) mode by uploading another software into the AP. The easiest way to do so is... ...from a WLC, and it requires that you do have the software available (trough a Cisco support contract).

Such AP have in their product name either "L" (for "LightWeight") or a "C" (for "CAPWAP based").

A standalone AP (without L or C in the name) may have been converted to lightweight mode. In this case the original software may still be present in flash, and you can reconfigure the AP to boot from the original software rather than the lightweight one.

Comment: Yes both are lightweight, and I dont want to covert them into autonomous. Infact I dont wana break AP connectivity with my PC in anyway, is it possible AP dhcp would assign interface address, if yes please guide me how and if no then how can I stop AP to revert back from static IP.

Comment: You can't set the AP IP address manually as long as it is a lightweight AP.  You can check your DHCP server to see what address it was given.

Comment: The APs should take an IP address form DHCP, if it's not the case the means there's no DHCP server available on the link. Anyway the AP will drop the dhcp lease and renew the same it does with fixed IP. You could boot in ROMMODE but you will not have the same features available. The easiest way is to let the AP join the WLC. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Due to shortage of time, I have to replace the AP's in WiFi networks, and I want to get the upgraded image from the already functional AP's and the images from AP's that have been uploaded by WLC. In a nutshell I want ISO backup without connecting AP with WLC and could replace in short time.